# I cant see math formulas.

Tags: support, mathjax

I do not know what I have done that I cant see math formulas in this site, I just see them as matjax!badly I need help.

Comment: You cannot see them? As in instead of the rendered MathJax, you see the unrendered MathJax?

Comment: YES EXACTLY!!!!

Comment: (1) Is this the case on all pages? (2) Have you tried restarting your web browser? (3) What about other MathJax enabled sites, like [here](http://www.mathjax.org/demos/tex-samples/)?  (4) Can you post a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: What are your operating system, browser (and version), and architecture (32bit, 64bit, iPhone or some tablet)?

Comment: 1.yes it is for all pages. 2.yes I loged out ,close my web browser,even try another one,fire fox and chrome .3.yes this site too. 4.every thing is normal except math symbols.

Comment: I am using windows 7!64 bit!chrome and fire fox last version.

Comment: I must add that every thing was alright,suddenly it went like that.

Comment: JavaScript is still enabled?

Comment: I dont know how shuold I check it?

Comment: In Chrome go to `Settings` then expand to `Advanced Settings` then in the `Privacy` section click on `Content Settings...`  (If you haven't manually changed it I doubt it's been changed.)

Comment: yes it is enable for all sites.

Comment: I really dont know what to do!I am confused!

Comment: I think when I was typing a question,I press view as HTML by accident,do you think this is the reason?if it is how should I fix it?

Comment: Are you having this problem on other MathJax-enabled sites, e.g. www.mathjax.org? Can you access cdn.mathjax.org, e.g. http://cdn.mathjax.org/mathjax/latest/test/examples.html?

Comment: May be clearing your browser's cache and cookies help, note that doing this signs you out of all sites you are currently signed in.